# how to 100 text field in table view ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

number of cell  in table view 100
and every cell having a text field and when ever  i am scrolling value should be present in text box . and one another LABEL show no OF index in Table view .

Comment: It does not work this way on StackOverflow. Show what you have tried, explain what is your issue or what part you are struggling with. What is your current result and what is your desired result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create data module class as below

```
class Data {
   var text:String?
}
```

then add 100 objects in array and load tableview from array.
Now create custom cell & take reference of textfield in custom cell class. Implement observer for text change on textField in this class.

Now write function as below in custom cell

```
func configureCell(data:Data){

}
```

call this function from cell for row at index path pass object at current index in this function.

Now declare local variable in custom cell which will hold reference of then object as below.

```
var data:Data?

func configureCell(data:Data){
self.data = data
 self.textField.text = data.text
}
```

now in text did change method update text in data.text property

```
func textFieldDidChangeText(textField:UITextField){
    self.data.text =  textField.text
}
```

set textField text to data.text, so value will be retained even you scroll the application