# Showing data from pickerview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I have designed a tableview cell with a textfield for pickerview. AndI have loaded 2 of those cells in my tableview. In order to show data from the pickerview this is what I did in `cellForRowAt...`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell: sellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sellProductIdentifier") as! sellTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self

        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        cell.pickerField.inputView = pickerView
        cell.pickerField.text = myData[0]//myData is an array with values from 1-10

        myCell = cell //The issue seems to be here.

        return cell
    }
```

And the picker view methods I have given like this...

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return myData.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return myData[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    myCell.pickerField.text = myData[row]
}
```

The issue is if I click on the 2nd pickerview the value I select is assigned to the textfield. But when I select a value from the 1st field that value is shown in the 2nd field instead of 1st.

**EDIT:** This is my code in `cellForRowAt`...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let cell: sellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sellProductIdentifier") as! sellTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self

    let pickerView = MyPickerView()
    pickerView.cell = cell
    pickerView.delegate = self
    cell.qtyPickerField.inputView = pickerView

    return cell
}
```

This is the picker view methods...

```
        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return myData.count
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return myData[row]
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {


            if pickerView is MyPickerView {

                if let cell = (pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell {
                    let indexpath = self.tableview.indexPath(for: cell)
                    if let index = indexpath {
                        (pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell?.qtyPickerField?.text = myData[index.row]

    }
    }
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2** . code of pickerview `didSelectRow`

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

if pickerView is MyPickerView {

        if let cell = (pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell {

            cell.qtyPickerField.text = myData[row]
            let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPath(for: cell)
            if let index = indexPath {
                (pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell?.qtyPickerField?.text = myData[index.row]
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it the duplicate question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323404/different-picker-values-in-different-cells-of-same-tableview and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344878/same-picker-not-working-for-different-cells

Comment: @rmaddy : Isn't it the same question you happened to close earlier ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344878/same-picker-not-working-for-different-cells Please have a look as I cant close it (no accepted answer) but the same question has been posted multiple times

Comment: Stop asking same questions multiple times and stop creating accounts to post the same question again n again.

Comment: I have added an answer to your question. Check if it works and delete all dupicate questions that you have added if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :**

As somebody mentioned in answer above

`myCell = cell` //The issue seems to be here.

is the culprit. Because every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` finishes your myCell will have reference to the last cell returned and not to the cell which is responsible for showing the `pickerView`.

First delete `myCell = cell` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

**Solution :**

Now all that you have to do is to figure out which cell which holds the textField which is responsible for presenting the pickerView.

Now there can be multiple solutions. Here is one

**step 1:** Create a subclass of PickerView

```
class MyPickerView : UIPickerView {
    weak var cell : MyTableViewCell? = nil
}
```

Use this pickerView in your code than `UIPickerView`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell: sellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sellProductIdentifier") as! sellTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self

        let pickerView = MyPickerView()
        pickerView.cell = cell //pass cells reference 
        pickerView.delegate = self
        cell.pickerField.inputView = pickerView
        //other code
}
```

Finally

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView is MyPickerView {
            if let cell = (pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell {
                cell.textField?.text = myData[row]
                let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
                if let index  = indexPath {
                    //now go ahead and update your data
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

There can be multiple variants to this solution. Some will agree that passing a cell reference to picker view is fine because cell will anyway hold a strong ref to picker and picker only holds weak ref to cell.

I personally feel passing indexPath as a param to picker makes more sense.  Finally when user picks something you will use the indexPath passed to picker to get the reference to cell and finally update the cell's textField.

**O/P:**

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

As OP is still confused I decided to modify his edit 2 and add it as part of answer

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if pickerView is MyPickerView {

            if let cell = (pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell {

                cell.qtyPickerField.text = myData[row]
                let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPath(for: cell)
                if let index = indexPath {
                    //this is only to show you how you can access indexPath
                    //and in future if you need to update your data source you can use it
                    //for now ignore this :)
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Should be good enough :) Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sandeep Bhandari But I missed something about what you said regarding 'updating my data' after the indexpath..maybe I'm not so skilled in swift...:) But did you mean anything like `cell.pickerField.text = myData[(indexPath?.row)!]`

Comment: @bvt :being sarcastic ? I dont have your complete code so it becomes a little difficult to compile your code. Yes you are correct but rather than adding ! which might lead to crash use either if let or nil coalescing operator. I have updated my answer for the same

Comment: @bvt : I still see your other questions on SO, please consider accepting the answer posted if it helped (which I believe it did :) ) and deleting the existing questions, they will not do any good to community

Comment: .@Sandeep Bhandari the problem is still persisting. No matter what value I select from the pickerview, the value displayed in the textfield is always 1.

Comment: @bvt : Now you are stating a different problem, Your earlier problem was no matter which textField user selects your text gets updated in second cell now what you are saying is textNot changing does that mean now you have reference to proper textField ?

Comment: @bvt : Put a break point in didSelectRow check what is the indexPath returned, check what is the value of .pickerField.text after cell.pickerField.text = myData[  if that doesn't help post ur code with updates I have suggested lemme have a look

Comment: in this line `(pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell?.qtyPickerField?.text = myData[index.row]` you have already assigned the picker value to the textfield. Do I need to do anything else too..?

Comment: Nope should be fine. Check whats the value of myData[index.row] when control reaches. Check if index is fine. So if you selected first cell index should be (0,0) check that, finally check if (pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell is nil if not (pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell?.qtyPickerField is nil if not check the value of (pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell?.qtyPickerField?.text after the above mentioned statement

Comment: whatever row of pickerview I select, printing `indexpath` gives `[0, 0]` and printing `pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell?.qtyPickerField?.text` gives 1. Maybe that's why the data in the textfield was always 1 as I stated in one of the comment above...

Comment: @bvt : Edit your question and update it with the current code lemme look at it and will help you out

Comment: I have edited my question with the code in `cellForRow..` and the picker view methods...Thanks...

Comment: @bvt : Checking

Comment: sure, @Sandeep Bhandari

Comment: @bvt : U der ?? Dude I was correct when I wrote (pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell?.textLabel?.text = myData[row] you confused me!! You should pick the data based on the currently selected row of picker rather than tableView othervise you will always end up seeing same number :D hahahaha I updated my code have a look

Comment: @bvt: Is there still a issue ??

Comment: There still seems to be an issue @Sandeep Bhandari. The textfields in the tableviewcells are still showing just 1 no matter waht is selected. Please have a look at the "EDIT 2" in my question. It has the code in pickerview `didSelectRow` I added as per your suggestion....

Comment: @bvt : Dude why do u still have "(pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell?.qtyPickerField?.text = noOfItems[index.row]" ?? Thats the issue remove it.

Comment: @bvt : The if condition I showed `if let index = indexPath {` its for future purpose like updating ur data source for now keep it empty or simply delete that if condition

Comment: so what should have been there instead of it..?

Comment: @bvt : Lemme post another update. Please copy paste it as it is :D

Comment: @bvt : Check my Edit 2 and use it as it is :)

Comment: Can u maybe suggest what was my biggest mistake in this case...?

Comment: @bvt : Am glad it did :) Happy that u managed to get it work :) This is certainly one of the longest answer I ever posted and most hard earned 15 points :D hahahahahaha

Comment: @bvt : What was the issue simple :) Your first statement cell.qtyPickerField.text = myData[row] would update your textField with proper value user picked using picker but then (pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell?.qtyPickerField?.text = myData[index.row] this would revert it to wrong value immediately so u always saw wrong value. Why  myData[index.row] is wrong ?? because index.row shows the row of textField which is selected what u need is the row user picked in picker isn't it ?? Thats all

Comment: Yup...:D if you don't mind could you just suggest what was I doing wrong..? maybe I can be careful about it next time..?

Comment: @bvt : Just did :D Now please go ahead and delete all duplicate questions to avoid consequences :) remember Never do that again :) finally looks like this is ur temp account deleting it would mean my hard earner 15 at stake hahahahahah so please be careful with that as well :D

Answer (score 1):

Problem starts with

```
myCell = cell;
```

You will always have instance of latest cell here. So assigning value in delegate will update textField in latest call.

what you can do in pickerView delegate is (Noob way though :p)

```
if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: INDEXPATH_OF_RESPECTIVE_ROW) { 
    "get text field instance and assign value."
}
```

Comment: Ok @Hussaan S you are suggesting that I make the change in the pickerview `didSelectRow`...?

Comment: Yes exactly. !!

Comment: but how can I get the indexpath there...?

Comment: As I mentioned, its a noob's way, you can init indexPath with section and row of the relevant cell. Otherwise If you really want to do it properly follow @Sandeep's answer

Comment: @hussaan-s : Identifying the issue was spot on :) Hence +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to Implement Picker view delegates in your custom cell class sellTableViewCell

you should implement picker delegate in custom cell so you don't have to take refrence of cell and update text in textfield of that cell. if you have these delegate methods implemented in cell then you have to update text in textfield of that instance of cell. so there will not be mixing of text in different cell. At the same time you have to update this value in your data model object for that indexPath in array so the value can be retained while you scroll. See my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303118/how-to-100-text-field-in-table-view-ios-swift/47303453?noredirect=1#comment81557769_47303453) link to know how to implement.